# G graph connections for finite groups G

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-groups

In my research, I have seen G graph connections usually when G is a Lie group and the graph is the fatgraph of a (punctured) surface. This is usually in a physics context. However, I am curious to know whether there is research on the problem of classifying G graph connections for finite graphs and finite groups, in a completely combinatorial setting, removing all physics and geometry contexts.